# tvOS app doesn't load JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, tvos, tvml, tvjs

I'm creating an tvOs app, while using TVML templates. I've run it in the simulator countless times, and on an actual Apple TV 2 also. When I tried to run it yesterday on the Apple TV, though, it didn't run correctly. The app was built and there were no errors, it just didn't load the JavaScript code of the application. The logs from the App Delegate were logged.

I then tried running the project in the simulator, and it worked. But when I tried today to run it in the simulator, I had the same problem.

I tried restarting my computer a couple of times, deleting the derived data folders, resetting the content and settings of the simulator, etc. I tested another TVML based application and had the same problem, so I don't think it is related to my project. I guess it's related to Xcode, but I'm not getting any errors, so I don't know what to do. Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem or how I could debug this problem?

I'm using Xcode 7.3.1 and my computer is a Macbook Pro running El Capitan.

The code that I use to load the JavaScript code is below, but this code worked before and I didn't change anything about it.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) 
    let appControllerContext = TVApplicationControllerContext()

    appControllerContext.launchOptions = [
        "initialJSDependencies" : initialJSDependencies()
    ]

    let javascriptURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("main",
        withExtension: "js")

    appControllerContext.javaScriptApplicationURL = javascriptURL!

    appController = TVApplicationController(
        context: appControllerContext, window: window,
        delegate: self)

    print('Test log')

    return true

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it by deleting the simulator and downloading it again; little weird about it suddenly changing though.